# Does C# have any built in parsing for config files other than app.conf

Tags: c#, .net, forms, configuration, config

I'd like to give the user the option to save/load parameters for a form from configuration files. I'd like there to be multiple configuration files where each file coincides with a different setup. These configurations can be loaded at any time, not just on startup. Does C# have any sort of built in support for this or would I have to write my own parser to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to let users hand edit these configuration files? If not, consider sqlite to store these?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could make use of profiles in ASP.NET. There is an introduction you can find here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420052/Implementing-User-Profiles-in-ASP-NET-A-Beginners